# Insulation pull tabs on PCB to turn on a device for the first time

Tags: power-supply, insulation

In some inexpensive electronic products like toys and remotes, there is a small piece of plastic sheet that disconnects a coin cell or button cell. Pulling out this plastic tab turns on the device, by connecting the battery.

Can a similar insulating tab be added to the PCB? Which kind of components can enable this? The two supply wires from the battery would be soldered to the PCB, so this tab needs to be on the PCB.

Comment: I guess you could do it with some kind of switch or something? perhaps a better question here would be why you want to do this? Sounds a bit like an x-y problem to me

Comment: Just use a 0.1" pitch jumper and pin header.

Comment: To whate end do you want this?

Comment: Exactly the same requirement as in the low cost toys, which is that its low cost and a one time switch-on. Just that in this case the supply from battery is in the form of two wires that's soldered onto the PCB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a toy that uses a spring loaded slide plunger switch that's released when the tab is pulled.

[image]
[image]
[image]

this switch is of the folded steel and pnenolic paper type,[image]

[image]

these could possibly work instead:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Jasen! Can you please show the 'spring loaded slide plunger switch' with better pics?

Comment: The spring loaded plunger would be a momentary normally closed switch, by holding the switch in the pressed position, it holds the contacts open

Comment: this one is normally open, but both types are available,  the blue one is DPDT, note that it has no hook so it's momentary, not latching.